# Modifying the list class

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm working through Functional programming in Scala and the first few chapters define this type of data structure:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

When I try to define a linked list like this; it works as expected:

```
val nums: List[Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)));
```

I am however trying to define a linked list like this, but I get a compilation error (Expression of type scala.collection.immutable.List[Int] doesn't conform to expected type List[Int]:

```
val nums: List[Int] = List[Int](1, 2, 3)
```

My question is - 1) Does declaring the data structure modify the internal class of List? 2) Why can't the second structure be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Does declaring the data structure modify the internal class of List?

No.

> 2) Why can't the second structure be used?

You are calling the `apply` method of the `List` object. The only object named `List` that is in scope is the [`scala.collection.immutable.List` object](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List$) and [its `apply` method](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List$@apply[A](xs:A*):List[A]) returns an instance of [`scala.collection.immutable.List`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List). However, you have declared `nums` to be of type `List[Int]`, not `scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]`, therefore the two types are not compatible.

You need to write your own `List` object, for example like this:

```
object List {
  def apply[A](elements: A*): List[A] = 
    if (elements.isEmpty) Nil else Cons(elements.head, apply(elements.tail :_*))
}
```